# How to integrate "Android-PanoramaDemo-master" this library into Android Studio for photo stitching?

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, image-stitching, dji-sdk, opencv-stitching

[I am refering to this library](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-PanoramaDemo)

I want to integrate it in Android studio for merging photos.
As this library is in Native i am having trouble to integrate it.
Can anybody provide me with proper steps and one example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The information is included in the code description, about 2/3rds down, the paragraph starts with this text:

> Right click on your project -> Android Tools -> Add Native Support. A
>   new folder named jni will be created in your project. Within it will
>   be two files: APPNAME.cpp and Android.mk (APPNAME being your app
>   name).